# Remove characters between 2 strings

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML file.

```
<products>
<product zid=&quot;cmslcmsdklcms&quot;>
<price>34</price>
<category>Football</category>
</product>
<product zid=&quot;kcnskcsks77789ds9&quot;>
<price>56</price>
<category>Rugby</category>
</product>
<product zid=&quot;343d34x&quot;>
<price>12</price>
<category>Volley</category>
</product>
</products>
```

I want to remove everything inside the  tag between zid and &quot included.
The result should be this:

```
<products>
<product>
<price>34</price>
<category>Football</category>
</product>
<product>
<price>56</price>
<category>Rugby</category>
</product>
<product>
<price>12</price>
<category>Volley</category>
</product>
</products>
```

I'd like to achieve this with PHP.

Comment: Does the XML file actually have `&quot;` in it, or does it have a `"`?

Comment: Did you really mean closing `&quot`s rather than `&quot;`s?  I think the former are invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `simpleXML` or `DOMDocument` would be better for XML, but for this regex is OK.  If there is always `zid=` then something like:

```
file_put_contents($filename,
    preg_replace('/ zid=[^>]+>/', '>', file_get_contents($filename)));
```

To be a broader replacement:

```
file_put_contents($filename,
    preg_replace('/<product[^>]+>/', '>', file_get_contents($filename)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run a [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) on the XML as a whole. Here is an example regex:

https://regex101.com/r/dK2jA1/2

Using that, you could do something like this:

```
$raw_xml = '<products><product zid=&quot;cmslcmsdklcms&quot><price>34</price><category>Football</category></product><product zid=&quot;kcnskcsks77789ds9&quot><price>56</price>
<category>Rugby</category></product><product zid=&quot;343d34x&quot><price>12</price><category>Volley</category></product></products>';

$pattern = "/(<product+.*>)./g";
$replacement = '<product>';

$clean_xml = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $raw_xml);
```

Which would replace all of the data similar to `<product zid=&quot;343d34x&quot>` with the empty tag equivalent of `<product>`

That should get you sorted.